# Как отформатировать число в запросе SQLite

Tags: android, база-данных, sqlite

Необходимо чтобы SQLite запрос выводил число с разделителями. 
К примеру: 12345 -> 12 345. Поддерживает ли SQLite какую нибудь функцию для данной цели?

Comment: имхо, зачем менять что то в базе, измените лучше в представлении.

Comment: Я в запросе объединяю строку с числом и вывожу его и выходит что то вроде: 'Текущие продажи: 12345' а нужно 'Текущие продажи: 12 435'. В представление такого рода значение немного тяжело форматировать, как я подумал.

Comment: Насколько я знаю SQLite подобное не поддерживает из коробки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite - язык запросов, излишне было бы наделять его чем-либо, не связанным с построением запросов и выборкой из БД. И не стоит забывать, что он все-таки LITE, т.е. множество его возможостей ограничено необходимым

Comment: Ясно спасибо, буду искать другие варианты

Comment: Вообще за правильный ответ тут принято галку ставить в благодарность за помощь

Answer (score 1):

Перед сохранением или при выводе значения, вызовите эту функцию:

```
 private String addPadding(String s) {
        StringBuilder retVal;

        if (s.length() <= 3) {
            return s;
        }

        retVal = new StringBuilder(s);

        for(int i = retVal.length(); i > 0; i -= 3){
            retVal.insert(i, " ");
        }
        return retVal.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Тимур спросил, можно ли преобразовать значение средствами SQLite. Ни к чему приводить тут методы других инструментов

Comment: О, капитан нарисовался. Если что я понял что спросил Тимур, и думаю он так понял из комментариев под постом, что sqlite такие фичи не поддерживает. Я лишь предложил вменяемое альтернативное решение.

Comment: У тебя такой большой рейтинг, наверно ты здесь гораздо дольше меня.. Так долго, что уже забыл пару правил из http://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Ого, действительно! Спасибо, что напомнил. Перед сном вместо "Отче наш" перечитывать буду